# Websphere: security-constraint in web.xml doesn't work

Tags: websphere, web.xml

I'd like to protect a single .jsp-page from anonymous access. I'm trying to do that the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>
t-webapp</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>
    ZServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ZServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    a.b.c.d.application.t.ZServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ZServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ZServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>
    TTests</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>TTests</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ttests.jsp</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>
        TServletRoles</description>
        <role-name>role_admin1</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>
    role_admin1</description>
    <role-name>role_admin1</role-name>
</security-role>
```

But whenever I'm accessing ttests.jsp, I'm getting access immediately - without having to fill username/password... what am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is security enabled on your was profile?

Comment: I just wanted to write the answer: enable global security in the admin console... wow... that's it... thanks for your response (if you write an "official" answer, I will accept it as solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be to make sure that global security is enabled on your websphere profile with the Enable application security check box checked.