# Redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS request without code change

Tags: java, websphere

My web application runs in shared server(Websphere), Now my application runs for both the HTTP and HTTPS request . Usually when the application runs it shows like below
https://localhost:9443/index.jsp. 
If the user try to change the https to http and submit the request, server accepts the request. I need to avoid the scenario and make the application to support only for https request on application level. Kindly anyone help me out.

Comment: Can you add a java servlet filter to check and redirect http to https?

Comment: You expect us to look at https://localhost:9443/index.jsp??

Comment: I dont want to intorduce filtering concept here, Is there any way to achieve it just by modifying the web.xml.

Comment: Just i gave the sample URL with HTTPS https://localhost:9443/index.jsp. i want to make it available even when the user modify it to http://localhost:9443/index.jsp in the URL.

Comment: Do you know what servlet filter is? It is done by adding entry into web.xml without modifying the rest of your code but you need to implement a filter, which is independent of the rest.

Comment: And you are not introducing a new concept. Servlet filter is a standard in Java servlet API.

Comment: I personally use Spring framework so I don't need to worry about this problem. However, learning Spring isn't easy. You will need at least a few months of experience in order to use Spring framework the way you want.

Comment: hi giga, thanks for your input. first pls understand , i knew well about filtering , for filtering anyhow we need to create one filter class with implementation in doFilter method(). But i dont want to introduce any new java class. have you ever tried below security-constraint in Tomcat or weblogic ,<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>https</web-resource-name>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <transport-guarantee>C

Comment: This security constraint works fine for both Tomcat and Weblogic and rediredts all http request to https. In such a way i need to find the solution for webspehere.

Comment: Presumably the port also has to change when the https is replace with http? WebSphere would give an error on http://localhost:9443

Answer (score 1):

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>https</web-resource-name>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

Add the above `user-data-constraint` in your web.xml. Which will redirect all the `http` request to `https`.

Comment: Hi ramesh , thanks for your quick reply i have tried this earlier posting this question, But the above <security-constraint> is working on Tomcat Web server its not working for Websphere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067917/websphere-security-constraint-in-web-xml-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for denying user non-https connection is to simply delete http transport chain; Go to Application servers > your server > Web container transport chains, select WCInboundDefault and click delete. Now you are left only with WCInboundDefaultSecure transport chain, which listens on SSL port.

Another alternative equally effective is to remove host alias for you non-https port at Virtual Hosts > default_host > Host Aliases- this feels like a less brutal configuration change :)

If you prefer redirection over restriction, I suggest you do it before you hit application server, for example at web server or load balancer. If you're using Apache HTTP server or IBM HTTP Server in front of WAS, you may manage the redirect with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that both global and application security are enabled in the WebSphere admin console.